# How do I add a background color (highlight) class names in VS code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I want to make the HTML file more readable on VS Code Editor by highlighting the class names as below.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Wgw.png)

I have come this far, but don't know what chunk of code to add next in *json file.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
"textMateRules": [
  {
    "scope": "entity.name.selector",
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#ff00ff",
      "fontStyle": "bold",
      
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If you want to change only class colors I have no idea. But you can try other vscode themes. You can look that [article for good themes](https://www.tabnine.com/blog/top-vscode-themes/).

for windows CTRL + K + T
for mac cmd + K + T

Comment: You cannot style the backgroundColor of syntax through the `tokenColorCustomizations` - only foreground and fontStyle as you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight)

Add this to your `settings.json` (Global or Workspace)

```
"highlight.regexes": {
  "( class=)(\"[^\"<>]*\")": {
    "regexFlags": "g",
    "filterLanguageRegex": "html",
    "decorations": [ 
      {  },
      { "backgroundColor": "#f0000040" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It works when I edit the *json file under the 'workspace' tab, though it does not work under the 'user' tab.